# Elevator Probability Problem giving two different answers

Tags: probability

21 people enter an elevator at the basement which has 40 floors above it. What is the probability 3 people exit on the $i$th floor? (ignore basement)

So I say that the probability is $\binom{21}{3}/40^{21}$ because 21C3 is the event space and 40^21 is the sample space.

However, when I use a binomial random variable, I get different answers:
$\binom{21}{3}*(1/40)^3*(39/40)^{18}$

Why are they giving different answers?

Comment: This can’t be answered without further information or assumptions. Please make those explicit.

Comment: @amd What questions do you have?

Comment: @amd I don't think there are any other possible assumptions. The elevator drops 21 people off (not in order) to 40 different floors.

Comment: Without specifying the probability distribution of the floor number each person exits on, your question cannot be answered.  You may be implicitly assuming that the probability that any single individual exits on a given floor is uniformly distributed, but that is an example of an **assumption** that is not stated.

Comment: @heropup It is uniformly distributed.

Comment: Notice that your first answer is different from your second answer by a factor of $39^{18}$.  This is explained by the fact that your first answer does not take into account the fact that everyone else has a choice of which floor to get off of.  Your answer of $\binom{21}{3}/40^{21}$ is the correct probability for the question of the probability that $3$ people exit on the $i$'th floor while the remaining 18 people exit on the first floor (*or the second floor if $i=1$*) which is different than the question of $3$ off on $i$'th floor and remaining 18 distributed among the remaining floors

Comment: Your first solution woefully undercounts the number of ways of distributing all of the passengers so that exactly three get off on the given floor.

Comment: @amd What scenarios are overlooked?

Comment: See JMoravitz’ comment.

Comment: Do the forty floors include the one where all the people get on?

Comment: @DJohnM No it does not

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I see. I completely forgot about the other choices for the people. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose for the sake of simplicity that:

1. The floor on which a given person exits is independent of the floor on on which any other person exits.
2. The floor that a given person exits on is randomly and uniformly selected by that person, including the first floor.

Now, for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 21$, define the random variable $$X_i \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1, 40), \quad \Pr[X_i = x] = \frac{1}{40}, \quad x = 1, 2, \ldots, 40.$$  This represents the random floor number that Person $i$ exits the elevator on.  We permit, therefore, a positive probability that a person enters the elevator (presumably from the first floor) and then, before the elevator can move, leaves the elevator.

Furthermore, let us define for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 21$ and $j = 1, 2, \ldots 40$, random variables $$B_{ij} \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 1/40), \quad \Pr[B_{ij} = 1] = 1/40,$$ which counts whether Person $i$ leaves the elevator at floor $j$; that is to say, $B_{ij} = 1$; or does not leave the elevator at floor $j$, in which case $B_{ij} = 0$.  Then because of Property #1 above, the random number of people exiting on floor $j$ is $$Y_j = \sum_{i=1}^{21} B_{ij} \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 21, p = 1/40), \\ \Pr[Y_j = y] = \binom{21}{y} \left(\tfrac{1}{40}\right)^y \left(\tfrac{39}{40}\right)^{21-y}, \quad y = 0, 1, \ldots, 21.$$  Hence $$\Pr[Y_j = 3] = \binom{21}{3} \frac{39^{18}}{40^{21}} = \frac{3^{18} \cdot 7 \cdot 13^{18} \cdot  19}{2^{62} \cdot 5^{20}}.$$  Because $X_i$ is uniform, the $Y_j$ are IID.

---

It is worth mentioning that it is important to **understand** the meaning of what is being enumerated.  Simply writing out expressions like $40^{21}$ means nothing unless you are able to explain what it represents.  Such a number would, for example, represent the number of ways to assign a floor number to each person, taking into account the fact that the people and floors are both distinguishable sets.  But if you write an expression like $\binom{21}{3}$, this represents the number of ways to select subsets of $3$ people from the group of $21$, without regard to the order in which they were selected, and more to the point, without any consideration of what it means to "select" those three people with respect to the floor they exit on.  So immediately, you can tell that you are not enumerating elementary outcomes in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

> So I say that the probability is $\binom{21}{3}/40^{21}$ because 21C3 is the event space and 40^21 is the sample space.

${}^{21}\mathrm C_3$ counts the selections of three people from twenty-one; without repetition.

$40^{21}$ counts independent selections of one from forty floors by twenty-one people; allowing repetition.

You are counting incomparable things.   If the sample-space is selections of floors by people, so too should be the event space; because it is a subset of the sample space.

The outcomes for your event-space needs to be: selections of the specified floor by three from twenty-one people and any from the 39 other floors by the remaining 18 people.   This is counted by: ${}^{21}\mathrm C_3\,39^{18}$

Answer (score 0):

A physical analogy approach:

Take $21$ white marbles and $39$ black marbles.  Arrange them in a straight line and look at it from left to right.  The white marbles represent the people, and the black marbles represent the division between each floor.  The white marbles *beyond* the $39$th black marble are the $40$th floor exiters.  The fortieth floor doesn't need a trailing divider, so there are only $39$ black marbles

These $60$ items, $21$ all identical and $39$ all identical can be arranged in $N$ ways:$$N = \frac{60!}{21! \times 39!}$$

This is the number of distinct distributions of indistinguishable passenger over the $40$ floors.

Now, assume that three passengers decide to walk to a common floor, and at the same time disable the elevator from stopping at that floor. The probability that they pick the $i$th floor is $\frac 1{60}$.

We are left with the remaining $18$ passengers to be distributed over the $39$ remaining floors.  With the same logic as above, this can be done in $N_1$ ways:$$N_1=\frac{56!}{18! \times 38!}$$

So, the probability that there will be exactly $3$ people get off at the $i$th floor is $P_i$:$$P_i=\frac{1}{60} \times \frac{N_1}{N}$$